Cannot pass multiprocessing.Manager to process when using forkserver: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
Sample code:
import multiprocessing

def main():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun, args=('p1', manager))
        proc.start()
        proc.join()

def fun(name, manager):
    print('fun:', name, manager)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Fails with error:
$ /opt/python3.12.6/bin/python3 ./demo_mp_manager_forkserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../demo_mp_manager_forkserver.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/.../demo_mp_manager_forkserver.py", line 7, in main
    proc.start()
  File "/opt/python3.12.6/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python3.12.6/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python3.12.6/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/context.py", line 301, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/python3.12.6/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/popen_forkserver.py", line 35, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/opt/python3.12.6/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/opt/python3.12.6/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/popen_forkserver.py", line 47, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, buf)
  File "/opt/python3.12.6/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref.ReferenceType' object


This is how you can access the main processes' BaseManager instance (in this case a subclass of BaseManager, i.e. SyncManager, which has registered methods that can be called. What makes this a little less than straightforward is that in the "usual" situation of where a custom BaseManager instance is being used for implementing clinet/server, the client (in this case your child process) knows by agreement the address of the server and what authkey it is using. In this case the SyncManager instance gets a random port address and authkey from its process and these need to be passed along to the client. The client also has to register the method names it will be calling upon the server.
Please read the comments in the code:
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

def main():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        # The child address must be passed the manager's address and authkey
        # in order to connect to this manager:
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=fun,
            args=('p1', manager.address, multiprocessing.current_process().authkey)
        )
        proc.start()
        proc.join()

def fun(name, address, authkey):
    manager = BaseManager(address=address, authkey=authkey)
    # Any methods we are to call on the manager we are connecting to must
    # first be registered:
    manager.register('dict')
    manager.connect()
    d = manager.dict()
    d['name'] = name
    print(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
{'name': 'p1'}


I guess you are supposed to use the manager to create shared objects and pass those objects to child processes, not the whole manager.
import multiprocessing

def main():
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        shared_dict = manager.dict()
        shared_dict['foo'] = 'bar'
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=fun, args=('p1', shared_dict))
        proc.start()
        proc.join()

def fun(name, shared_dict):
    print('fun:', name, shared_dict.items())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Output:
$ /opt/python3.12.6/bin/python3 ./demo_mp_manager_forkserver.py
fun: p1 [('foo', 'bar')]

But if you really really need to share the whole Manager with the child process, you can create a BaseManager object in the child process and connect it to the already running manager process.
See BaseManager.get_server()
and BaseManager.connect().

I don't think the get_server method is relevant to this issue but connect certainly can be used -- but it is not straightforward. See my answer.
